# Ckeditor: on dom change event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible to hook into the process of creating elements in the dom of ckeditor? For example, every time the editor wants to append a **p** element into the dom, I would like to set some custom attributes on the element before it is appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going throught the specs I stumbled upon the [dataprocessor](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor.html), which transforms the dom into html and allows to hook into the process of building the element's html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
  var editor = e.editor;
  editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    elements: {
      p: function(e) {
        e.attributes.style = 'padding: 20px;';
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Mind that data processor in specific for each instance of ckeditor.